# What is the error inside in this ajax code?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Below is my code for the checking username from database using Ajax.The input text from html page is not going to the checkusername.php `$_POST['uname'];` What might be the error? I tried everything still its not working.How can the value in the username textbox  be brought into the checkusername.php file ,when the button is clicked?

html page code

```
<input type="text" name="uname" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="UserName (0-9,A-Z,a-z)">
<input type='button' id='check_username_availability' value='Check Username Availability'>
  <div id='username_availability_result'></div>
```

checkusername.php

```
<?php

   $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","database")or die(mysqli_error());

   //get the username
      $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['uname']);

       //mysql query to select field username if it's equal to the username that we check '
          $result =mysqli_query($con,"Select username from users where username='$username'") or die(mysqli_error($con));


      //if number of rows fields is bigger them 0 that means it's NOT available '
       if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
     //and we send 0 to the ajax request
    echo 0;
    }else{
    //else if it's not bigger then 0, then it's available '
    //and we send 1 to the ajax request
    echo 1;
     }


        ?>
```

//script for checking live username availability

```
   <script>



 $(document).ready(function() {

    //the min chars for username
    var min_chars = 6;

     //result texts
    var characters_error ='Minimum amount of chars is 6';
     var checking_html = 'Checking...';

    //when button is clicked
     $('#check_username_availability').click(function(){
         //run the character number check
         if($('#username').val().length < min_chars){
             //if it's bellow the minimum show characters_error text '
            $('#username_availability_result').html(characters_error);
         }else{
             //else show the cheking_text and run the function to check
             //$('#username_availability_result').html(checking_html);
             check_availability();
            }
        });

         });

    //function to check username availability
     function check_availability(){

    //get the username
    var username = $('#username').val();

    //use ajax to run the check
    $.post("checkusername.php",{ username: uname },
        function(result){
            //if the result is 1
            if(result == 1){
                //show that the username is available
                $('#username_availability_result').html(username + ' is Available');
            }else{
                //show that the username is NOT available
                $('#username_availability_result').html(username + ' is not Available');
            }
          });

    }




    </script>
```

Comment: You can find the error yourself by checking the console after you fire the request

Comment: $.post("checkusername.php",{ username: uname }, i doubt error is somewhere here ,but cant diagonise it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swap values:

```
{ username: uname }
```

to this:

```
{ uname: username }
```

As the php is expecting a var named `uname` as per this `$_POST['uname']` while you were sending `username`.
So, the simple change is to swap the properties in the object.

Comment: Thanks @Jai for the help

Answer (score 1):

Simple typo.

Change

```
var username = $('#username').val();
//use ajax to run the check
$.post("checkusername.php",{ username: uname },
```

To

```
var username = $('#username').val();
//use ajax to run the check
$.post("checkusername.php",{ uname: username },// Observe username.
```

Comment: would it not be `{ uname: username }`, as the php looks for `$_POST['uname']`...?

Comment: Thanks a lot for finding it .. console response 200 OK
80ms 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You are posting to checkusername.php 
`{username: uname}`
and trying to get `$_POST['uname']` and in js you don't have the `uname` variable.
Change `{ username: uname }` to `{ uname: username }`